# Metrics and features for comparison of aggregated trail dataset

Tags: data, gps, spatial-statistics, clustering

I have hundreds GPS traces generated by cars for single road in the city from direction A to B.
And I have hundreds of GPS traces generated by people which organized in trail in the mountain from bottom A to top B point.

What kind of features and attributes can be derived from trail and city road to compare them? I want find similiariry and differences between mountain walking data and vehicle city road.

For now, I derived following features:

- distance between consecutive points
- duration between points
- average speed
- trail density (# of points per sq. meter).

What else attributes can be derived to compare?